# uploading to box.net with post request in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest, box-api

I want to upload file on box.net via api and I am posting my file via post request in this way

According to Documentation of Box.NET here is the request url

```
https://upload.box.net/api/1.0/upload/<auth token>/<folder id>
```

here is the documentation http://developers.box.net/w/page/12923951/ApiFunction_Upload%20and%20Download

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://upload.box.net/api/1.0/upload...;
request.Method = "POST";

byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\a.docx");

request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();
dataStream.Close();
response.Close();
```

I am getting exception with this message "upload_no_files_found"

Comment: Looks that you have done all the steps from MSDN, but what this line  `Console.WriteLine` have to do with asp.net ?

Comment: Yeah aristos.. I was testing the different things. i was writing in debug. its mistaken...

Comment: actually we are passing the authtoken that have all the information. and other thing is folder name where to post and posting my file stream to that api.

Comment: I cant expose my authtoken here but you can see in the first line where i am creating my request. I am passing the oauth token

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](http://developers.box.net/w/page/12923951/ApiFunction_Upload%20and%20Download)  on the Sample Upload request the Box.net request some parameters like the `new_file1`, `share` and `emails[]`.

So you need to send this parameters and not only the file alone. From [MSDN sample for how to post parametres](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4cek6cc.aspx) the key point is to make this full string with the file that you going to send. I focus on this line that is made the parameters with the file to send.

```
    string postData = "firstone=" + inputData;
    ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding ();
    byte[] byte1 = encoding.GetBytes (postData);
```

For your case this can looks like

```
    string postData = "share=1&emails[]=test@domain.com&new_file1=" + FileData;
    ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding ();
    byte[] byte1 = encoding.GetBytes (postData);
```

and your final code must be like:

```
     WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://upload.box.net/api/1.0/<auth_token>/<file_id>/<version_id>;
     request.Method = "POST";

    // open and read file
    byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\a.docx");

    // make the parametres
    string postData = "share=1&emails[]=test@domain.com&new_file1=";
    ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding ();
    byte[] parametres = encoding.GetBytes (postData);

    // set the Type
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    // the full length.
    request.ContentLength = parametres.Length + byteArray.Length;

    // now we go for post
    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    // send the parametres
    dataStream.Write(parametres, 0, parametres.Length);
    // follow the file
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

    // flush and close what you have send  
    dataStream.Close();
```

Now this is the idea, but I can not debug this code nether test it, maybe is not work as it is from the first and need some changing and debug.

Comment: Thanks. Let me test that. I will tell you in next 5 mins

Comment: @ArslanPervaiz I have write that is not easy to work right away and I can not debug it, but this the line that you need to follow to find the solution.

Comment: @Aritros: Yup I am already tangling with that and finding any solution. I posted on box.net api as well but they are unable to answer. So thats why I posted here to get some help. Anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

This may help. I am using v2 API and RestSharp.

```
    // as per http://developers.box.com/docs/#files-upload-a-file
        RestClient client1 = new RestClient();
        client1.BaseUrl = "https://upload.box.com";
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.Resource = "api/2.0/files/data";
        string Headers = string.Format("BoxAuth api_key={0}&auth_token={1}",
                api_key,
                AuthToken);
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", Headers);
        request.AddParameter("folder_id", FolderID);
        request.AddFile("filename", filePath);

        //request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        var response = client1.Execute(request);
        return response.Content;
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating folder and Uploading Document VIA Box.net and BOX API

```
public void Upload_Doc(string folder_id, string accessToken)
    {
   var client = new RestClient("https://upload.box.com/api/2.0");
    var request = new RestRequest("files/content", Method.POST);
    request.AddParameter("parent_id", folder_id);

    request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);

    string path = @"D:\Project\21Teach\Documents\screenshots.docx";
    byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);

    request.AddFile("filename", byteArray, "screenshots.docx");

    var responses = client.Execute(request);
    var content = responses.Content;
}
static string folderCreation(string APIKey, string authToken)
{

    RestClient client = new RestClient();
    client.BaseUrl = "https://api.box.com/2.0/folders";
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    string Headers = string.Format("Bearer {0}", authToken);
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", Headers);
    request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\"name\":\"Youka\",\"parent\":{\"id\":\"0\"}}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
    var response = client.Execute(request);
    return response.Content;



}
```